# how to show all values in heatmap

Tags: python

I am trying to come up with heatmap for correlation and I realized some are wrong.

Below is my heatmap. As you can see, the number for the action are not appearing.

```
import numpy as np 
from pandas import DataFrame
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
Index= ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
Cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
df = DataFrame(abs(np.random.randn(5, 4)), index=Index, columns=Cols)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```

[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBySf.png)

Comment: This is a known bug